# Pyspark replace multiple strings in RDD

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to replace multiple strings in a **pyspark** rdd. I would like to replace these strings **in length order** - from longest to shortest. The operation will ultimately be replacing a large volume of text, so good performance is a consideration.

**Problem example:**

In the below example, I would like to replace the strings:

```
 replace, text, is
```

with, in respective order (longest to shortest):

```
 replacement1, replacement2, replacement3
```

i.e. if the string **replace** is found, this should be replaced with **replacement1** and in this example the first to be searched and replaced.

The strings will also be stored as a pyspark rdd as follows:

```
+---------+------------------+
| string  | replacement_term |
+---------+------------------+
| replace | replacement1     |
+---------+------------------+
| text    | replacement2     |
+---------+------------------+
| is      | replacement3     |
+---------+------------------+
```

See example of the rdd which needs to be replaced with the above terms:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | text                                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 1  | here is some text to replace with terms |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 2  | text to replace with terms              |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 3  | text                                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 4  | here is some text to replace            |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 5  | text to replace                         |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
```

And I would like to replace, creating the rdd output as following:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | text                                                           |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | here replacement3 some replacement2 to replacement1 with terms |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | replacement2 to replacement1 with terms                        |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | replacement2                                                   |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4  | here replacement3 some replacement2 to replacement1            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 5  | replacement2 to replacement1                                   |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: So if you have an rdd with the replacement terms predefined, what does "replace these strings in length order" mean? It's not allowed to replace them all at once?

Comment: There is a likelihood of two strings colliding in my problem. For example ‘is’ and ‘is not’ both contain is. I’d prefer to use the longer string in my use case. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Following code snippet works for `Spark` / `Scala` & `DataFrame`s *API*.
Try to adapt it to `RDD` & `PySpark`

```
// imports
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// spark-session (not needed if your'e in spark-shell)
implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("SO").getOrCreate()

// you'll be reading it from somewhere
val dfToBeModified: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
  rowRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
    Row(1, "here is some text to replace with terms"),
    Row(2, "text to replace with terms"),
    Row(3, "text"),
    Row(4, "here is some text to replace"),
    Row(5, "text to replace")
  )),
  schema = StructType(List(
    StructField("id", IntegerType, false),
    StructField("text", StringType, false)
  ))
)

// it should preferably be read not as a dataframe but as a sequence  
val dfWithReplacements: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
    rowRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
    Row("replace", "replacement1"),
    Row("text", "replacement2"),
    Row("is", "replacement3")
  )),
  schema = StructType(List(
    StructField("string", StringType, false),
    StructField("replacement_term", StringType, false)
  ))
)

// dfWithReplacements must not be too big or your executor will crash
val seqWithReplacements: Array[Row] = dfWithReplacements.collect()

// there you go
val dfWithModifications: DataFrame = seqWithReplacements.foldLeft(dfToBeModified) { (dfWithSomeModifications: DataFrame, row: Row) =>
    dfWithSomeModifications.withColumn("text", regexp_replace(dfWithSomeModifications("text"), row(0).toString, row(1).toString))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ll give this a shot and post Pyspark version. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Shubham, how the map replacements can be used instead fo dfwtihReplacement dataframe, like val replacements= Map( "replace" -> "replacement1", "text" -> "replacement2", "is" -> "replacement3")

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming you **can not** collect the replacement terms rdd,
but also assuming the replacement terms are a single word:

First you need to flaten the text (And remmember the word order).

Then you do a left join to replace the words.

Then you reasemble the original text.

```
replacement_terms_rdd = sc.parallelize([("replace", "replacement1"),
                                        ("text", "replacement2"),
                                        ("is", "replacement3")])

text_rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, "here is some text to replace with terms"),
                          (2, "text to replace with terms "),
                          (3, "text"),
                          (4, "here is some text to replace"),
                          (5, "text to replace")])

print (text_rdd\
.flatMap(lambda x: [(y[1], (x[0], y[0])) for y in enumerate(x[1].split())] )\
.leftOuterJoin(replacement_terms_rdd)\
.map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], (x[1][0][1], x[1][1] or x[0]) ))\
.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: " ".join([y[1] for y in sorted(x)]))\
.collect())
```

Result:

```
[(1, 'here replacement3 some replacement2 to replacement1 with terms'), (2, 'replacement2 to replacement1 with terms'), (3, 'replacement2'), (4, 'here replacement3 some replacement2 to replacement1'), (5, 'replacement2 to replacement1')]
```

Comment: If your replacement terms are not necessary one word but you know the max length of any replacement term, this can easly be fixed by taking ngrams from the text. Of course it will hurt the performance.

Comment: Thanks! The terms could indeed have more than one word, please could you show the ngrams solution? Thanks!